# Installing SDL2 on aws Red Hat 7.4

Tags: redhat, sdl-2

So I have been banging my head on this for a while today. I need to get a C environment supporting SDL2 developer working with clang on an AWS free tier RHEL 7.4 server.
When I try to complete yum install SDL2-devel I get the following at the end of the install run:

--> Package SDL2-devel.x86_64 0:2.0.3-9.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libxkbcommon-devel for package: SDL2-devel-2.0.3-9.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mesa-libGLES-devel for package: SDL2-devel-2.0.3-9.el7.x86_64
---> Package libXScrnSaver.x86_64 0:1.2.2-6.1.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: SDL2-devel-2.0.3-9.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: mesa-libGLES-devel
Error: Package: SDL2-devel-2.0.3-9.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libxkbcommon-devel
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

The rpm cleanup command does not help.
Neither does yum clean all, or similar.

When I check those dependencies the -devel objects are not listed.
The binary libraries for both of the are present and correct.

Any idea how to get these devel packages installed?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a programming question.  Usually, such errors occur if you enable the EPEL repository without enabling the optional channels first.  It looks like `mesa-libGLES-devel` and `libxkbcommon-devel` are only available through optional channels such as `rhel-7-server-optional-rpms` (and EPEL 7 also needs the extra channels). So you need to run a command like:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms --enable=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
```